# How do I show a loading image in JQuery?

Tags: jquery, ajax

I am trying to show a loading image on a login page before it redirects to profile page. I am logging user through facebook api, so it takes time to show profile page and I want to show loading image until it goes to profile page. Please note that I am validating the page to itself.

My HTML is:

```
    <div>
     <a id="facebookLogin" class="fbButton" href="' . $loginUrl . '"><img src="f-connect.png"></a><br>';
    </div>

<div id='loadingmessage' style='display:none'>
  <img src='loading.gif'/>
</div>
```

My JQuery is:

```
$( document ).ready(function( $ ) {

            $('#facebookLogin').live('click', function() {
                        $('#loadingmessage').fadeIn(); 
                }); 
        });
```

When I click the facebook connect button, it doesn't show the loading image and goes to profile page if it was successful. Please help!!

Comment: What version jQuery are you using? `live` has been deprecated for a while. Use `on` instead.

Comment: I am using 1.8.23, I tried your solution but it's still not working. If I do an alert, it will work on `live` but the code is not working

Comment: Try with `.show()` rather than `.fadeIn()` so it's immediate. Browsers may not allow the animation to finish since navigation has started.

Answer (score 2):

Your issue is when you click your link, you are getting redirected immediately, so there is no time for the loader to fade in. You need to cancel the default behaviour and use AJAX:

```
$(document).on('click', '#facebookLogin', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $('#loadingmessage').fadeIn(); 
        $.ajax({
         type: "POST",
         url: FACEBOOKAPIURL,
         data: SOMELOGINDATA,
         success: function(){ $('#loadingmessage').fadeOut(); }
    });
});
```

I'm afraid I'm unfamiliar with Facebook's API, unfortunately, but you should be able to find what you need in their Developer site: https://developers.facebook.com

Comment: it's not working. When I try your code, the facebook button doesn't even work, but when I try your code replacing document and putting the selector instead,, it works as before without showing a loading image

Comment: This code won't actually work, as I don't know how to login via Facebook's API, so you'll have to research that bit or ask another SO question. What this code will do is stop the link from working, which is intended, and will then bring up the loading message. After that, you must discover how to authenticate with Facebook via AJAX, and once that authentication has succeeded, you can do something like fading out the loading message or redirecting to another page.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I will try to see if I could authenticate Facebook via AJAX